# Scrape the data from a website that loads the data from JavaScript / JSON Array (POST request) using Python

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the data from [this link](https://www.ikh.se/sv/arbetskladsel--skyddsutrustning--skyddsprodukter/brandskydds--och-forsta-forbandsprodukter)

I have tried this way

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import csv

# specify the url
urlpage =  'https://www.ikh.se/sysNet/getProductsJSON/getProductsJSONDB.aspx?' \ 
'sua=1&lang=2&navid=19277994'

# query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage)
# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'dnsCell'})
text = (''.join(tag.stripped_strings))
print (page)
```

I got the HTML dom but the product list dom are missing. Actually I guess the product list dom manages by a JSON array that requests from [this link](https://www.ikh.se/sysNet/getProductsJSON/getProductsJSONDB.aspx?sua=2&lang=2&navid=11994180) but **I am not sure** about the product list dom load method. I am right or wrong.
I want to scrape the all product details from this [site](https://www.ikh.se/sv/ikh-se-framsida) and export in Excel.

Comment: What is the end results suppose to look like?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

The requests library does not load the Javascript. If you want to download completely rendered website, use selenium library : https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: can you add example code then i can understand better

Comment: https://medium.com/cs-note/web-crawling-by-using-selenium-python-3-4fff0bdb4c65
: - This may help you